# Automapper from EF(to EF) not possible?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

So I wanted to make a own custom mapper earlier but I got the advice that it is difficult(because I got refrences etc, and I agree with that ^^) and that I ll have more luck with automapper since it is easy etc. So I started creating mapping for the classes I want to convert (I want to make this application to update a SQLserver database from a SQLite file on a weekly base, the table names and properties are the same, only the capitals are not the same, but automapper is case insensitive so great)

Here is the Code I tried:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<person, Person>();
Mapper.CreateMap<personAbility, PersonAbility>();
Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

Then I get the error that person doesn t know how to convert the personabilities propertie. So I googled and found out that I need to include it:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<person, Person>()
.Include<personAbility, PersonAbility>()
Mapper.CreateMap<personAbility, PersonAbility>();
Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

However here it complains that it is not personability it needs but a list(EntityCollection). So I tried:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<person, Person>()
.Include<EntityCollection<personAbility>, EntityCollection<PersonAbility>>()
Mapper.CreateMap<personAbility, PersonAbility>();
Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

However it gives an error that it doesn t know the type, and I googled some more finding: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Lists-and-arrays On the support list there isn t a EntityCollection. Meaning I ran into an other wall(dead end)??? Anyone knows a solution for this, if you got an other solution/way to map my database, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why can't you use a collection or list?

Comment: Because EF(entity framework), what I use to map the databases, makes put collections in a EntityCollection.

Comment: EF puts the collection into a list. Can you include the code before the mapping? And maybe the code behind your models (Person & PersonAbility)?

Comment: I didn t write any code, I just went to "Add new Item" -> Data -> ADO.NET Entity Data Model -> select the database and press next next in the wizard. Then a edmx file is made, and it got all code auto generated

Comment: What about the code for the classes `person` and `personAbility` that you're trying to create a map for?

Comment: I found the solution myself Joe, thanks for the help, Check my Answer if you want to know how I got it finnaly fixed :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finnaly got it fixed. I was on the wrong way with include. I just needed to map the collection too

Adding this line fixed it:(and removing the include line)

```
        Mapper.CreateMap<EntityCollection<personAbility>, EntityCollection<PersonAbility>>();
```

Thanks for all the effort

Answer (score 0):

I am not positive, but you may need to create the map for PersonAbility before creating the map for Person, since mapping Person's depends on being able to map PersonAbility's